# Spatial multiplexing MIMO, antenna critical spacing, antenna isolation

Tags: wireless

How does antenna isolation affect single user spatial multiplexing MIMO performance? Text books talk about a critical antenna spacing in a rich scattering environment of 1/2 of the wavelength. Would that be the sole criterion? or would the antenna-antenna  isolation rather be the criterion to observe?

Comment: Try the signal processing forum at https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's more to it than just the antenna spacing.  You want to minimize the amount of coupling between the two (or more than two) transmit or receive antennas.  Spacing is one way to help in this regard.  Another is to orient the antennas differently so that their patterns do not overlap as much.  A third is to use different polarizations for each antenna.

Comment: So suppose two  64 QAM MIMO streams are to be received and that the SNR required to detect these signals is 20 dB, while the antenna isolation is only 15 dB, would this work? I would think it would not or do you perhaps have another point of view?